# leaflet Uncaught TypeError: t.onAdd is not a function

Tags: arrays, exception, leaflet

i have this exception when clicking the checkbox options in the leaflet layer control, the objetive of this code is to load all the makers based on a type, these markers goes into the subsarrays and subarray goes into "arreglos"

arreglos has 2 objects:

- subbarr, this is the subarray wich contains all the markers of this type
- nombre, this is the type of the marker

---

this is the code

```
layerControl = new L.control.layers();


for(i=0;i<arreglos.length;i++)
{

var layerg = new L.LayerGroup();


var grupo= arreglos[i].subarr;

for(e=0;e<grupo.length;e++)
{
layerg.addLayer(grupo[e]);
}

var nombre = arreglos[i].grupo;

layerControl.addOverlay(layerg, nombre); 

}

layerControl.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Can we see the entire block of code in a fiddle?

Comment: there you go https://jsfiddle.net/r3exwve6/1/

Comment: Two things. 1 - You are including Leaflet Draw twice.You only need `<script src="../src/Leaflet.draw.js"></script>`, not all the other `<script src="../src/Toolbar.js"></script>` and etc lines.

2.You have included PHP into this page(`var content`)...It will not render here. Sounds like you need to post this onto a real server before we can debug further.